# vuejs2 checking if value is true gives unexpected results

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

AM performing an ajax request and i would like to check if results from http request is true or false but am getting very unexpected results

Am doing this

```
axios.post("check-user")
.then(
    (res) => {
    if (res.data) { //return value is either true or false
        console.log("its true");
    } else {
        console.log("ites false");
    }
})
```

The above always executes false

When i try

```
axios.post("check-user")
.then(
    (res) => {
    if (res.data === true) { //return value is either true or false
        console.log("its true");
    } else {
        console.log("ites false");
    }
})
```

the last one works

Why does `if(res.data)` fail while `if(res.data === true)` work.

Comment: It's possible that your response result looks as a string and `if('false')` will pass.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai thats true checking with typeOf shows it as a string. How can i then convert that to a boolean of true or false

Comment: Just use `res.data == 'true'`

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI You can use `Boolean(res.data)`